# How does Time machine handle a new startup drive?

Tags: time-machine

I've been running my machine for years and using Time Machine all that time.  Now I have just decided that I needed a separate system partition for some work stuff where I wanted to have the whole system configured differently (different utilities installed, different defaults, different drivers for things, etc.)

So I did this, but now we come to turning on Time Machine.  Near as I can tell, TM appears to recognize that this is still the same computer and wants to continue backing up as always to the same TM archive it's always used.

For probably obvious reasons I don't want to do this, I want this backup to be completely different from the old one.  In fact I don't even want to back up any of the other drives/partitions connected to this machine while booted off this partition.

Is there a way to make this happen or am I stuck because it's the same physical machine and that's all TM cares about?

Comment: [Backing up Multiple Drives/Partitions (on the same Mac)](http://www.baligu.com/pondini/TM/32.html)

Comment: OK so it appears that I want to "Back up both, from both OSX volumes, to the same volume." however that article does not appear to give any information on how exactly to accomplish this.